# Visualizing x,y,z coordinates in Ruby/Python?

Tags: python, ruby, data-visualization, coordinate-systems, graph-visualization

I want to draw a continuous line through coordinate points I have stored in a hash, in 3D if possible, but probably 2D to start with.

I'd like to process about ten points/sec so that I can see the line being drawn over time.

Does anyone know a good way to visualize this? I have considered Python scripting in Blender, but I am wondering if there's a quicker way to get a working prototype.

Comment: seems to me that `matplotlib` should be able to handle something like this pretty easily...

Comment: where do you need to see the results? in a desktop GUI, in a Web page, ... or simply you need a JPEG/GIF/PNG file with that?

Comment: When it comes to drawing lines in Python, can't get much simpler than the built-in [turtle](http://docs.python.org/3/library/turtle.html) framework. There's also [tkinter](http://docs.python.org/3/library/tkinter.html), which can get you a window with lines drawn on it in about two dozen lines of code.

Comment: @mgilson does matplot operate in realtime or are they strictly static graphs?

Comment: @BenKnudson -- It can operate in real-time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than use Ruby or Python solely for this, I'd recommend taking a look at the "[D3.js](http://d3js.org/)" library.

You can take advantage of the browser's ability to generate graphics, and the D3 library's multitude of different plots and charts. It's very impressive and should be easy to integrate with Python or Ruby acting as the data generators, feeding the browser via JSON.

Comment: It is, and there are some very interesting charts that inspire new ways to look at data. We're trying to get it in front of our managers where I work to get them to buy in to re-engineering some of our dashboards.

Comment: very interesting, would be cool if you could interact with and manipulate the data from the graphic itself.. does D3 have any options that make this possible?

Comment: It does if you add it. Once the data is in your JavaScript, you could do what you want. D3 is just the visualization part, not the data manipulation part of the interface.